# How split mysql table use CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this problem, a table(table name is contents) have 6 million record in my project.
 I want to split this table(contents) and use in cakephp, but I don't how to do.

Please help me.

Thanks!

`CakePHP version : 2.x`

Comment: What database do you use, mysql?

Comment: yes, I use mysql_5.how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to split the table? You can do an export with `phpmyadmin` and import the content into another table(with same structure).

Comment: yes, your right, I am also the meaning. import the content into another table(with same structure), Such structure consistent table has a lot of. but I don't know how to achieve use cakephp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)? This may be a better option without a lot of extra work required.

Comment: you are right, but mysql Didn't seem to Didn't seem to Partitioning. partitioning is Oracle's concept.

Comment: MySQL handles partitioning from v5.1 forward. So if you are using 5.1 or higher, you are good to go. Just look at the link in my answer. Click on Partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL, you can split the table in two (or more) and create a [MERGE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/merge-storage-engine.html) from them. Then you can access the merge as if you had only one big table. No changes are required to your program.

Here's an example of how to create a merge table from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/merge-storage-engine.html):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ->    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->    message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
mysql> CREATE TABLE t2 (
    ->    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->    message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t1');
mysql> INSERT INTO t2 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t2');
mysql> CREATE TABLE total (
    ->    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->    message CHAR(20), INDEX(a))
    ->    ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

The best way to use merge tables depends on your situation. If you have to split large table because it's already too large, you would create other tables with the same structure (`create mySmallTable1 like myBigTable`) and then move a part of the data into each (`insert into mySmallTable1 select * from myBigTable where ...`). Obviously this will take some time because MySQL has to copy records from one file to another. Then drop the big table and recreate it as a merge of the small tables.

If the big table is fine as it is but you don't want to insert new records into it you would do a different thing: Create a new table with the same structure as the big table. Define a merge of the new and the big table so that new inserts go into the new table (the `INSERT_METHOD` option)

Comment: You have two table with same structure MERGE. but I have one big table(5G). now, do I need to split the big table and import it into structure consistent table (has a lot of)? then MERGE them?

Comment: I couldn't fit an answer to that into a comment so I updated the answer instead

Comment: thank you a lot!~ Chuck Burgess is right I should to see Mysql's Manual